# Returning an integer number in the Fibonacci Series in Python

Tags: python, fibonacci

I am trying to build a function which will take the n and return the nth integer in the Fibonacci series.
For example:
Fibonacci series:

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, .....
```

if the function is Fibonacci, then it will return: `Fibonacci(8)= 21`

Now, I am writing the function like this:

```
    def Fibonacci(a):
        ls = []
        for i in range(0, a):
            if i==0 or i==1:
                n=1
            elif i>=2:
                n=ls.append(ls[i-1]+ls[i-2])
        print(n)
        
    Fibonacci(8)
```

Which shows the error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any solution?

Comment: `ls` should be starts with 2 values `[0, 1]`

Comment: What do you think `append` returns, and what does it *actually* return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is close to be working, here are some insights and improvements:

1. The list is empty, so you get an exception at line 7 for trying to access past elements
2. Initialize the list with `[1, 1]` (if you expect `fib(8)=21`)
3. `append` doesn't return value
4. Use function name with lowercase letters and separate words using underscore

```
def fibonacci(a):
    ls = [1, 1]
    for i in range(2, a):
        ls.append(ls[i - 1] + ls[i - 2])
    return ls[-1]

# 21
print(fibonacci(8))
```

Bonus fact:

Using mathematical tricks you can find the n-th number with few mathematical operations (instead of iterating over past values):

```
import math

SQRT_5 = math.sqrt(5)

def fibonacci(n):
    return int(((((1 + SQRT_5) / 2) ** n) / SQRT_5) + 0.5 )
```

Read more on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) at "Relation to the golden ratio".

Comment: you can start the loop directly form `2` to `a`

Comment: Small detail. Don't start function with a capital! I know OP had the same but it is still worth noting :) Apart from that. Upvoted for a clear and correct answer.

Comment: The exact formula is `(phi**n - (1-phi)**n) / SQRT_5` where `phi = (1 + SQRT_5) / 2`. Have you tested the formula you're suggesting? Can you link some paper or blog post or any source with an explanation of why it works?

Comment: I’d really like to see an implementation of exponentiation which runs in O(1).

Comment: @Stef my source is Wikipedia added it, they have great explanations for the mathematical formalization of that formula - enjoy :)

Comment: I compared the two formulae `a = int(((((1 + SQRT_5) / 2) ** n) / SQRT_5) + 0.5 )` and `b = int((phi**n - (1-phi)**n) / SQRT_5)` for `n in range(0,100)` and got results differing by `1` for n in [71, 76, 77]

Comment: I guess it's due to the precision approximation of float numbers, mathematics still hold. Anyway changed to the other version. @Stef

Comment: Of course it's due to the approximation. Exponentiation increases errors **a lot**, so a small approximation error in `phi` will turn into a big error in `phi**n` for a large `n`. The question is, which of the two formulae give the better approximation, and until which value of `n` is this approximation good enough (keeping in mind that we're rounding to the nearest integer, so an error less than `.5` is okay).

Comment: Actually my mistake was truncating with `int()` instead of rounding with `int( ... +.5)`. When rounding, both formulae give the same results (as expected after reading the wikipedia explanation) up until a `OverflowError: (34, 'Numerical result out of range')` occurs because `fib(n)` becomes too large for python floats anyway. I don't know whether those results are exactly the fibonacci numbers, though, even if they are equal :p

Comment: Tl;dr: you shouldn't have trusted me and no matter which formula you use, you should keep the `+.5` before calling `int()`.

Answer (score 3):

Appending to a list makes no sense for a Fibonacci number implementation; you only need to store the last two numbers, since all previous numbers no longer figure into the computation:

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a
```

This is arguably something like the “canonical” implementation of this series in Python.

The specific issue in your implementation is that your list is initially empty and isn’t getting filled for i<2. Hence, once your loop reaches i=2, you are attempting to access two elements in the list which don’t exist.

Answer (score 1):

it is because there are no elements in the array when you get to i >= 2, so you should change this line

```
n = 1
```

to

```
ls.append(1)
```

because otherwise there will be no elements in the array when you try accessing it later

and then

```
return ls[-1]
```

or

```
print ls[-1]
```

it is also more efficient to calculate fibonnacci numbers like this:

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 1, 1

    for i in range(n-1):
        a, b = b, a+b

    return a
```

Comment: Sorry, fixed it

Answer (score 1):

### `IndexError` and how to track the bug

The `IndexError` can only be triggered by trying to access an item in a list; this only happens on the `n=ls.append(ls[i-1]+ls[i-2])` line in your code.

To help debug, you might add a `print` statement just before that line, and print `i` and `ls`, so you know the values of the variables when the program crashes.

### The mistake and how to fix it

In this case, the answer is simple: your list `ls` begins empty, and you try to access `ls[i-1] and ls[i-2]` before adding any element to the list.

I suggest initializing the list with `[0, 1]` since those are the first two Fibonacci values, and the only ones you never append to the list in your current code.

### A second mistake and the final corrected code

Additionally, `ls.append(...)` appends an element to `ls`, but doesn't return a value, so after appending the value, you should store it in `n` with an extra line `n = ls[-1]`. Note that in python, "the element in position `-1`" is just a shorthand for the element in position `len(ls) - 1`, *i.e.*, the last element in the list.

```py
def fibonacci(a):
    ls = []
    for i in range(0, a):
        if i==0 or i==1:
            ls = [0, 1]
            n=1
        elif i>=2:
            ls.append(ls[i-1]+ls[i-2])
            n = ls[-1]
    print(n)
```

*Note that I called the function `fibonacci` instead of `Fibonacci`. You might think this is a personal preference, but programming languages sometimes have well-established conventions and style habits. I recommend naming your variables and functions with lowercase. Reserve the uppercase for class names and exceptions.*

### Further improving your code

When calculating `Fibonacci(a)`, the only values you need are `Fibonacci(a-1)` and `Fibonacci(a-2)`. Keeping the whole list of previous values in memory is not needed; all you need to keep are the previous two values. Try to write a new Fibonacci function, with the same logic as before, but only keeping two values in memory instead of the whole list!

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out how to fix your code, but I'd like to start from the drawing board. The Fibonacci problem is a really great way of getting to grips with **recursion** - if you haven't done so already. A recursive function here will be much more readable and likely quicker than looping through lists.

There are hundreds of worked solutions to the Fibonacci problem in Python online, e.g. [here](https://gist.github.com/klmr/301e1eca5aa096fb7cf4d4b7d961ad01#file-fib-py).

Comment: I completely agree that you’d usually implement the Fibonacci sequence using recursion (even in Python, despite Python’s bias against using recursion). But the solution linked to on the page you’ve linked is a bad solution because it (completely unnecessarily!) has exponential runtime. A good recursive Fibonacci implementation runs in O(n), same as the iterative solution.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm sure you're right. I was in too much of a hurry to push an answer out, and I just grabbed the first result there was. If you have a particular link in mind, I'd be more than happy to amend my answer. I see that you've posted a typically masterful recursive solution of your own. But I got here first, dammit!

Comment: The solution I’ve posted isn’t recursive. But a “proper” recursive solution uses the same two accumulators found in my answer: https://gist.github.com/klmr/301e1eca5aa096fb7cf4d4b7d961ad01#file-fib-py

Comment: @KonradRudolph I do apologise. As always, you're quite right. I'll amend my answer just now.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fibonacci(n):
    ls = []
    for i in range(0,n):
        if (i==0) or (i==1):
            n=1
            ls.append(n)
        elif i>=2:
            ls.append(ls[-1]+ls[-2])
            n=ls[-2] + ls[-3]
    print(n)


while(True):
    x = int(input())
    fibonacci(x)
```

we created a list and if n>=2 we added new element which is sum of last 2.
Then we printed new last 2. and 3. elements sum which is the answer...